# How to draw a scaled version of images from the system ImageList?

Tags: delphi, scale, timagelist

I create and initialize the `TImageList`...

```
ImageList:=TImageList.Create(self);
ImageList.ShareImages:=true;
```

I get the system ImageList handle for small icons (16x16)...

```
ImageList.Handle:=SHGetFileInfo('',0,FileInfo,SizeOf(FileInfo),SHGFI_SYSICONINDEX or SHGFI_SMALLICON);
```

And now I want to draw the icons on my control canvas scaled to 50x50 pixels. How I do this ?

Comment: Could not it be 2 pixels smaller ? 48x48 px ?

Comment: No, I said 50 for example, but I want tot be able to scale it to any size.

Comment: Better get a 48x48 or bigger and scale it down, instead of stretching a 16x16 to 50x50. in any case you use `ImageList.GetBitmap` and do what ever you want with it. or even better get an Icon handle from it, and use [`DrawIconEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648065(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Yes, it is always better to scale down than to scale up.  You will have better image resolution that way.

Comment: on second thought, `DrawiconEx` wont work with stretching an icon :/

Comment: @Marus Nebunu, I asked because you might get an icon of the exact size (if you were lucky enough) and you would need no scaling (which will look ugly) unless you use a resampler. Of course, as others already mentioned, scale down from large image to smaller.

Comment: When it comes to scaling up 16x16 icons, you just don't do that. If you need larger icons you can use `SHGFI_ICON` instead of `SHGFI_SMALLICON`. You can get size (width and height) with `GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXICON)` and `GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYICON)`

Comment: Do you care about the quality of the result? Do you mind if the icons look horrid?

Comment: @kobik your second thought is not correct, DrawIconEx will stretch icon, but results will always be a bit off.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar, yep. my first thought was correct. later, I confused it with `ImageList_DrawEx` which does not stretch the icon.

Comment: Don't worry, I will draw it from the nearest icon size :) Thanks !

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Upscaling small icons is never good idea. 16X16 icon is too small to use it in any other way other as-is.

For start you can get larger shell images using

```
ImageList.Handle:=SHGetFileInfo('',0,FileInfo,SizeOf(FileInfo),SHGFI_SYSICONINDEX or SHGFI_ICON);
```

Those images will be generally 32x32 pix, but to be on safe side (if Windows are running in high DPI mode) you can get correct size from system

```
uses
  Winapi.Windows;

var
  IconWidth, IconHeight: integer;

  IconWidth := GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXICON);
  IconHeight := GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYICON);
```

You can also get even larger shell images with `SHGetImageList` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762185%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

To retrieve icon from you ImageList (if ImageList contains icons, and in your case it does) you can use:

```
ImageList.GetIcon(Index: Integer; Image: TIcon);
```

For scaling icons, while preserving transparency, to custom dimension you can use following code:

```
procedure StretchDrawIcon(Canvas: TCanvas; Dest: TRect; Icon: TIcon);
begin
  DrawIconEx(Canvas.Handle, Dest.Left, Dest.Top, Icon.Handle, Dest.Right - Dest.Left, Dest.Bottom - Dest.Top, 0, 0, DI_NORMAL);
end;
```

Answer (score 10):

Since an extracted Icon can not be stretched with StretchDraw and a extracted Bitmap would lose the transparency one way might be to extract the Icons and manipulate the destination canvas using [SetWorldTransform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/dd145104%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
uses Shellapi, Math;

Procedure SetCanvasZoomAndRotation(ACanvas:TCanvas;Zoom:Double;Angle:Double;CenterpointX,CenterpointY:Double);
var
    form : tagXFORM;
    Winkel:Double;

begin
      Winkel := DegToRad(Angle);
      SetGraphicsMode(ACanvas.Handle, GM_ADVANCED);
      SetMapMode(ACanvas.Handle,MM_ANISOTROPIC);
      form.eM11 := Zoom * cos( Winkel);
      form.eM12 := Zoom *Sin( Winkel)  ;
      form.eM21 := Zoom * (-sin( Winkel));
      form.eM22 := Zoom * cos( Winkel) ;
      form.eDx := CenterpointX;
      form.eDy := CenterpointY;
      SetWorldTransform(ACanvas.Handle,form);
end;

 Procedure ResetCanvas(ACanvas:TCanvas);
begin
   SetCanvasZoomAndRotation(ACanvas , 1, 0, 0,0);
end;

procedure TDemoForm.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
 FileInfo:_SHFileINfoW;
 ico:TIcon;
 ImageList:TImageList;
 i,x,y:Integer;
 zoom:double;
begin
  ImageList:=TImageList.Create(self);
  ImageList.ShareImages:=true;
  ImageList.Handle:=SHGetFileInfo('',0,FileInfo,SizeOf(FileInfo),SHGFI_SYSICONINDEX or SHGFI_SMALLICON);
  ico:=TIcon.Create;
  try
  x := 0;
  y := 0;
  zoom := 50 / Imagelist.Width;
  SetCanvasZoomAndRotation(Canvas,zoom,0,0 ,0);
  for I := 0 to ImageList.Count-1 do
   begin
    ImageList.GetIcon(i,ico);
    Canvas.Draw(x,y,ico);
    inc(x,Imagelist.Width);
    if (x + Imagelist.Width) * zoom > width then
        begin
        x := 0;
        inc(y,Imagelist.Height);
        end;
   end;
  finally
    ico.Free;
    ResetCanvas(Canvas);
    ImageList.Free;
  end;
end;
```

An example using 250 as desired size:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

`TImageList` does not support drawing a scaled image, it draws the image as-is.  The only option it provides is to let you specify the X/Y coordinates where the image should be drawn on the destination Canvas.

To scale an image, you will have to extract the desired image to a temporary `TBitmap` first and call its `Draw()` method, which allows you to specify the desired rectangle on the destination Canvas.  The bitmap will then stretch/scale its drawing to fill that rectangle as needed.